Sequence of tenses and the meaning

When I sleep she tries to break in

This sentence number 1 implies that during my sleep she tries to break in.
2.When I slept she tried to break in
I think when we backshift it to the past. Sentence number 2 remains with the same meaning. It means during my sleep she tried to break up. In other words 2 is the same as "when I was sleeping she tried to break in". That is what I think about my sentence number 2 but chat gpd told me that 2 means after my sleep she tried to broke in. That's why I am asking you to see if I am right?
EDIT
I will try to make my problem clear. Look at these examples please. "When I play a concert people scream" and " when I am playing a concert people scream". To me both have the same meaning that is people scream probably all the time during my concerts certainly I don't feel that it is a single scream. Yet, when I move my examples to the past " when I played a concert people screamed" and "when I was  playing a concert people screamed" both to me imply that that scream took like 2 seconds and that it was short. I feel that to show that screaming took time I'd need to write
"When I was playing a concert people were screaming". Is it just my feeling that is wrong or is there a change in meaning?
Maybe the meaning depends if it was a single occurance or something that happened many times?
EDIT
In school I was taught that we use past continuous to show a long event and past simple  to show a shorter one for instance.
A) "I was sleeping when a phone rang"
To me it is clear that that ringing was very short and didn't take to much time. I think that now I undertand that if the verb shows or implies that the action is long like here "sleep" I could also use simple and you'd still think that ringing happened during my sleep. Still, if I move this sentence to the present "I am sleeping when a phone rings". It doesn't imply to me that there was only one ring. So to sum it up now I think that if we treat A as a single occurance than I'm right that there was a single short ring but on the other hand if I think that A implies a situation that hapenned many times than scream isn't a single short event excatly the same as it is my in present version. Does it make sense?

You might like to check out the difference between 'when' and 'while'.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the misapprehension that ChatGPT can speak English.

A native speaker would say While I was asleep she tried to break in.

I'm not sure what you're asking. Yes, the second sense is basically just recasting the first in past tense. The first sentence could mean that she is trying to break in now (while you sleep), or it could be an "eternal present", meaning that every time you sleep or often when you sleep she tries to break in. The second sentence means she did this at one specific time, or perhaps, depending on context, at several specific times.
Side note: When I first read this, I took it to mean that she tried to break into your sleep, that is, that she tried to invade your dreams. You probably need to be more specific. Like, "When I slept, she tried to break in to my apartment." (Maybe the bigger context would make that clear.)

I will try to make my problem clear. Look at these examples please. "When I play concerts people scream" and " when I am playing concerts people scream". To me both have the same meaning that is people scream probably all the time during my concerts certainly I don't feel that it is a single scream. Yet, when I move my examples to the past " when I played concerts people screamed" and "when I was playing concerts people screamed" both to me imply that that scream took like 2 seconds and that it was short. I feel that to show that screaming took time I'd need to write

"When I was playing concerts people were screaming". Is it just my feeling that is wrong or is there a change in meaning?
